# How to replace unicode in ejs

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, ejs, unicode-string

I am using ESJ to make some dynamic string, EJS is converting the string with Unicode character,

**Sample code**

```
let name = "Shopper's Stop";
ejs.render('Client name is <%= name %>', {name: name}) // Client name is Shopper&#39;s Stop
```

Desire output:  Client name is ***Shopper's Stop***

I have tried with a workaround something like this :

```
ejs.render('Client name is <%= name %>', {name: name}).replace(/&#39;/g, "'") // Client name is Shopper's Stop
```

I am looking for a more reliable solution which can replace all Unicode Or a better way to handle this by **EJS**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing apostrophes to double quotes in `ejs.render('')` to `ejs.render("")`.

@edit
Try changing escape code `<%= name %>` to unescaped `<?- name ?>`

Comment: No, I am taking  `'Client name is <%= name %>'`   value from  API call, So there will not be a conflict with apostrophe  ( **'**).

`ejs.render( media.title  , {name: name})  //  media.title = Client name is <%= name %> `

Comment: @AmitKumar ok, I get it now. Try `<?- name ?>` - this should not escape the character

Comment: I tried with `<?- name ?>` ,  got the output :  Client name is <?- name ?>.